# Filter SwiftUI object Array

Tags: swiftui

I'd like to filter an array of object if the todoStatus === true and then return the count but I am unsure of how to go about it,I can already get the count of the entire array, but I'm not sure how to filter it down.

Here is what the structure looks like:

```js
class ToDo: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    @Published var todoName: String = ""
    @Published var todoStatus: Bool = false
    
    init (todoName: String, todoStatus: Bool) {
        self.todoName = todoName
        self.todoStatus = todoStatus
    }
}

class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var todos: [ToDo] = []
    init(_ todos: [ToDo]) {
        self.todos = todos
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var name = "Leander"
    
    @ObservedObject var state: AppState = AppState([
         ToDo(todoName: "Wash the Dogs", todoStatus: true),
         ToDo(todoName: "Wash the Dogs", todoStatus: false),
         ToDo(todoName: "Wash the Dogs", todoStatus: true),
         ToDo(todoName: "Wash the Dogs", todoStatus: false),
         ToDo(todoName: "Wash the Dogs", todoStatus: true),
         ToDo(todoName: "Wash the Dogs", todoStatus: false),
        ])
```

and how I'm accessing the count

```js
                       Text("\($state.todos.count)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this simple code, no need for the `$state`, just `state`, and no need for the `$0.todoStatus == true`:

```
  Text("\(state.todos.filter{$0.todoStatus}.count)")
```

Note, you should **not nest** `ObservableObject`, like you do, that is,
`class AppState: ObservableObject`  containing an array of `class ToDo: ObservableObject`. Use

```
struct ToDo: Identifiable {
    let id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var todoName: String = ""
    var todoStatus: Bool = false
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback and insight, I will definitely implement that now

Comment: if my answer helped, could you mark it as accepted please, using the tick mark, it turns green.

Answer (score 1):

You would simply use the `.filter` function on `Array`, then `.count` it like this:

```
let todoStatusCount = state.todos.filter( { $0.todoStatus } ).count
```